# Relationship and mahram

Tags: relationships

Assalamualikum. I have a question. I know a boy who is kind of sexually attracted to his mother. But it was all in his mind. He never did anything bad with his mother in reality. His parents are very religious and they don't know anything about it. So the boy realize his fault and he did tawba. But the question is is his mother become haram to his father. Also the boy has some physiological issues too. So what should he do

Comment: Why should his mother become haram for his father? This doesn't even make sense because first all was in the boys mind and secondly as his mother is a mahram and haram for marriage for him similar to any woman his father married or will marry in future. IMHO his parents should know and help him seek professional help.

Comment: I think he should go to a psychologist because these feelings of insecest is not good at all.